# Changes from TeXlive 2017 -> 2020: kvoptions issue

Tags: xetex, texlive, document-classes, compilation-error, texlive-2020

I changed recently to another computer and made a new TeXLive installation (2020). The old machine is running with TeXLive2017 (shame on me).

Now I run into trouble compiling some of my documents (XeLaTeX).
One of the documents is based on [this cv repository](https://github.com/Roald87/xelatex-cv-roald). On my old machine I can compile it, with the new installation it isn't possible anymore.
I was unable to reduce it to a minimal example, but the error log is huge and I cannot extract the failing point with my limited experience. (I will provide the log if needed). Until then, this repo should work as minimal example.
My suspicion is, that something changed with handling of the classes, so here are my to questions:

1. Are you able to compile the provided repository successful with TeXLive2020?
2. Are there changes in TeXLive concerning the handling of classes? Where can I find resources on that topic?

EDIT: The problem is originating from kvoptions-patch. An issue was created and I will update, if a solution is found. [Reference to issue](https://github.com/Roald87/xelatex-cv-roald/issues/6)

Comment: the class relies on kvoptions-patch but kvoptions-patch has been disabled as it is not compatible with a current latex. The class will have to rewrite its option handling.

Comment: That's helpful! With "The class will ..." you refer to the cv-class (cv-roald) or to kvoptions-patch? Do you have a recommendation what should be my first step to solve the problem by myself?

Comment: the class cv-roald will have to be adapted.  open an issue at the github and let the author handle it.

Comment: I will do that. Do you have some package alternatives to kvoptions-patch? Then I can solve that by myself and open a PR. Faster resolution for me and less work for the maintainer.

Comment: no, basically the documentclass option handling is quite restricted and one should avoid to put keyval settings there. There are plans to extend this, but it is not easy to do without breaking lots of existing document--kvoptions tried to do it with the patch, but as you can see its code wasn't stable enough and now fails.

Comment: https://github.com/Roald87/xelatex-cv-roald/issues/6
Issue for reference.

Comment: Thank you for your work! I will post an answer to my question and rephrase it for further reference. If you prefer, you can formulate an answer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference an answer to mark this question as solved.

As @Ulrike Fischer pointed out, there is the class `kvoptions-patch` loaded, that isn't compatible with TeXLive2020. The issue will be solved by changes in the repository.

Changes will be tracked in the [GitHub Repository](http://github.com/Roald87/xelatex-cv-roald/issues/6).